# How to to an orderby on a ManyToMany relation field

Tags: symfony, doctrine

i got an entity called "Recipes" that has a relation with another entity called "Ingredients".

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Ingredients::class, inversedBy="recettes")
 */
private $ingredient;
```

What i need is to list all ingredients via my form builder, and it works well :

```
->add('ingredient', EntityType::class, [
            // looks for choices from this entity
            'class' => Ingredients::class,
            'choice_label' => 'nom',
            // used to render a select box, check boxes or radios
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'label' => 'Ingrédients de la recette'
        ])
```

But i need to list them ordered by their name, so i've tried to add this line on my "Recipes ingredient field" :

```
* @OrderBy({"nom" = "ASC"})
```

But ingredients remains not ordered by their name.

Am i missing something ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * ...
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"nom" = "ASC"})
 */
private $recettes;
```

or

```
->add('ingredient', EntityType::class, [
            // looks for choices from this entity
            'class' => Ingredients::class,
            'choice_label' => 'nom',
            // used to render a select box, check boxes or radios
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'label' => 'Ingrédients de la recette',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                  return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->orderBy('u.nom', 'ASC');
             },
        ])
```